# counting incidences of a number and associated value in two synchronized lists

Tags: python, python-2.6

I have two lists that are of the same length:

```
alist = ['XX', 'HH', 'GG', 'XX', 'II', 'PP', 'LL', 'TT', 'KK', 'XX']
blist = [2, 3, 5, 5, 9, 8, 9, 4, 7, 2]
```

I want to know what values in alist have the same number in blist. I want the outcome to look like this:

2 = XX; 3 = HH; 5 = GG, XX; 9 = II, LL; 8 = PP; 4 = TT; 7 = KK

I solved it like this:

```
from collections import defaultdict
adict = {}
a = zip(blist, alist)
for key, value in a:
    adict.setdefault(k, []).append(v)
```

which gives this result:
adict:

```
{2: ['XX', 'XX'], 3: ['HH'], 4: ['TT'], 5: ['GG', 'XX'], 7: ['KK'], 8: ['PP'], 9: ['II', 'LL']}
```

but I dont want the same value twice, for example 2: ['XX', 'XX'] - I would like to have instead 2: ['XX'].

```
I tried this using 'set' before the list of values:
a = zip(blist, alist)
for key, value in a:
    a.setdefault(k, set[]).append(v)
```

but it complained...
any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd personally use Martijn's `defaultdict` approach, but I thought I'd address the issues with your current attempt.

The problem with your code:

```
a = zip(blist, alist)
for key, value in a:
    a.setdefault(k, set[]).append(v)
```

Is That:

- after the `zip`, `a` is now a list, so it won't support `.setdefault`
- `k` is not used in the for loop - it should be `key`
- `v` is not used in the for loop = it should be `value`
- `set[]` is invalid synatx - to create a new `set` - use `set()`
- A `set` does not have an `.append` - instead you want to use `add`

Corrected code:

```
d = {}
a = zip(blist, alist)
for key, value in a:
    d.setdefault(key, set()).add(value)
```

Adapt the following as desired to print:

```
for k, v in d.iteritems():
    if k > 5:
        print '{0}: {1}'.format(k, ','.join(v))
```

Comment: Cool :) but when i print this out to a file, it also prints 'set', like: 2: set(['XX']), 3: set(['HH']) etc.. why does it print 'set'?

Comment: Iterate over it taking key,value and format those how you want beforehand

Comment: f.ex. if i do: 
for key in d.keys():
    if key > 5:
      print key, d[key] for key in d.keys():
    if key > 5:
      print key, d[key]

I get:
7: set(['KK']) 
8: set(['PP'])
9: set(['II', 'LL'])

how would i get:
7: 'KK'
8: 'PP'
9: 'II', 'LL'

Answer (score 2):

Use the `defaultdict` type you imported but otherwise ignore:

```
from collections import defaultdict

a = defaultdict(set)
for k, v in zip(blist, alist):
    a[k].add(v)
```

results in:

```
>>> a
defaultdict(<type 'set'>, {2: set(['XX']), 3: set(['HH']), 4: set(['TT']), 5: set(['GG', 'XX']), 7: set(['KK']), 8: set(['PP']), 9: set(['II', 'LL'])})
```

`defaultdict` is a subclass of `dict` and behaves in the same way otherwise.

Comment: This gives me: `defaultdict(<type 'set'>, {2: 'XX', 3: 'HH', 4: 'TT', 5: 'XX', 7: 'KK', 8: 'PP', 9: 'LL'})`
I think he wants the value of 5 to contain both GG and XX.

Comment: @glormph: oops, indeed, corrected. I made an assumption about `.update()` that doesn't hold for defaultdict.

Answer (score 0):

Use your code and then add:

```
a = {x: set(a[x]) for x in a }
```

Comment: I cant use this, it says it´s invalid syntax...?

Comment: Which python version are you on? This works from python 2.7 I think